# lanzar evento cuando valor de jspinner cambie

Tags: java, eventos

queria que cuando cambie el valor del jspinner me muestre por pantalla un mensaje cualquiera (con System.out.printnl("hola") por ejemplo). El problema es que no se como lanzar un evento cada vez que se cambie el valor del jspinner. Y con cambiar me refiero a solo cambiar, es decir, que no sea cuando se cambia el foco o se pulsa enter sino en el mismo momento de cambiar su valor. Por cierto el jspinner esta incrustado dentro de un campo de una tabla. Esta es la clase principal:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class JSpinnerInTables {
    static String[] columnNames = {
        "Name","Value"
    };
    static Object[][] data = {
        {"one",1.0},
        {"two",2.0}
    };
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JTable table = new JTable(data,columnNames);
        //table.setSurrendersFocusOnKeystroke(true);
        TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();
        TableColumn tc = tcm.getColumn(1);
        tc.setCellEditor(new SpinnerEditor());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(table);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

y este el de la clase que crea el jspinner dentro de un campo de una tabla:

```
public class SpinnerEditor extends DefaultCellEditor
{
    JSpinner spinner;
    JSpinner.DefaultEditor editor;
    JTextField textField;
    boolean valueSet;

    // Initializes the spinner.
    public SpinnerEditor() {
        super(new JTextField());
        spinner = new JSpinner();
        editor = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor)spinner.getEditor());
        textField = editor.getTextField();
        textField.addFocusListener( new FocusListener() {
            public void focusGained( FocusEvent fe ) {
                System.err.println("Got focus");
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if ( valueSet ) {
                            textField.setCaretPosition(1);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            public void focusLost( FocusEvent fe ) {
            }
        });
        textField.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae ) {
                stopCellEditing();
                
            }
        });
        
    }

    // Prepares the spinner component and returns it.
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(
        JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column
    ) {
        if ( !valueSet ) {
            spinner.setValue(value);
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                textField.requestFocus();
            }
        });
        return spinner;
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable( EventObject eo ) {
        System.err.println("isCellEditable");
        if ( eo instanceof KeyEvent ) {
            KeyEvent ke = (KeyEvent)eo;
            System.err.println("key event: "+ke.getKeyChar());
            textField.setText(String.valueOf(ke.getKeyChar()));
            valueSet = true;
        } else {
            valueSet = false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Returns the spinners current value.
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
         
        //System.out.println("viva el vino");
        return spinner.getValue();
       
    }

    public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        System.err.println("Stopping edit");
        try {
            editor.commitEdit();
            spinner.commitEdit();
        } catch ( java.text.ParseException e ) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Invalid value, discarding.");
        }
        return super.stopCellEditing();
    }

    
}
```

Comment: Google: "JSpinner java 8", abrir la documentación y mirar los métodos disponibles... 10 segundos más tarde: [addChangeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html#addChangeListener-javax.swing.event.ChangeListener-). Te habría costado menos que escribir toda esa pregunta :P